# What means a class name in constructor of other class?

Tags: php, oop

I read some scripts and
I cannot understand  why they put a class name in a constructor of other class:

```
public function __construct(AclassName $foo){
$this->foo=$foo;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they want `$foo` to be an instance of `AclassName` only. Not an array, number, string, or an instance of a class that is not `AclassName` nor extends `AclassName`. In PHP is called [**type hinting**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), although they're not really hints, but enforcements.

```
function foo (array $bar) {
    // $bar must be an array, otherwise an E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR is thrown
}

function baz (ClassName $bar) {
    // $bar must be an instance of ClassName
}

baz(new ClassName); // works OK
baz(new StdClass);  // error

class ExtendsFromClassName extends ClassName
{}

baz(new ExtendsFromClassName); // works OK
```

Hinting may be done on interfaces or abstract classes too:

```
interface SomeInterface
{}

function baz(SomeInterface $object) {
    // $object must be an instance of a class which implements SomeInterface
}

class Foo implements SomeInterface
{}

baz(new Foo); // works OK
```

Comment: Wait.. what? Ionut, did you just edit Brandon's answer, cut out his code and paste it to yours? BAD FORM. Flagged -1.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. Looking at the edit history it appears Ionut edited the below answer by mistake and added his code samples to it. He then removed those changes and added them to his answer here. My bad.

Comment: @hobodave, I thought I edited my answer when I first added the code. After the edit I noticed it was Brandon's answer, so I rollbacked my edit on his answer and added the code to my answer. I'm not that kind of guy, which is an impossible kind in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a reference in an instance of the class associated with the constructor to an instance of `AclassName`. Presumably, then, the instance of the class associated with the constructor will collaborate with the `AclassName` instance to fulfill one or more of its responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Type Hinting, and was added in PHP5. Basically, it means that the supplied value for that argument of the method/function *must* be an instance of that class name. If it is not, the PHP engine will throw a catchable fatal error.

Here's a simple example based on the snippet you provided:

```
class AnotherClass 
{
    /**
     * @var SomeClass
     */
    protected $_someClass;

    public function __construct(SomeClass $some) {
        $this->_someClass = $some;
    }
}


$someClass = new SomeClass();
$differentClass = new DifferentClass();

// Fatal Error: Argument 1 must be an instance of SomeClass
$anotherClass = new AnotherClass($differentClass); 
$anotherClass = new AnotherClass('a string');


// That's ok!
$anotherClass = new AnotherClass($someClass);
```

Type hinting, like the `instanceof` operator takes class inheritance and interface implementation into consideration.

You can find the [relevant PHP manual page here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Answer (score 0):

`AclassName` is a type-hint. This means, that the first argument passed to the constructor must be an instance of `AclassName`.